# how to fit toolbar according to the screen resolution?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am new in the javafx development programming. I am developing the one desktop application for my company. My problem is how I fit the toolbar according to the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen bounds in Javafx like this:

`Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();`

Then you pass the bounds to Scene:

`Scene scene=new Scene(root,screenBounds.getWidth(),screenBounds.getHeight());`